# Unable to set property to a node in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-cql

I'm trying to set a property to node in neo4j as below.

```
MATCH (n:Person) 
where  n.first_name = "test_user" 
set n.last_name = "user_test" 
RETURN n LIMIT 25
```

And im getting `org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionFailureException:` error in browser.

[image]

Updating nodes of other label is working fine. I replaced graph.db to older version but still problem not solved.

Comment: Your query looks fine, so my guess is it's something else. What version of Neo4j are you using, and did you upgrade from some older version, and if so, how?

Comment: Im using neo4j 3.0.1 and i upgraded long back

Comment: do you have an unique constraint on the last_name property for nodes with Person label and a Person node already exists with value user_test for its last_name property?

Comment: Nope. I have created index on first_name.